# ImportError with rpy2 and Python 2.7

Tags: python, django, rpy2

I am running Django with a virtual environment (python 2.7) and need to use the `rpy2` module.  However, when I run my server, I get the following error:

```
/opt/site/env2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/rinterface/_rinterface.so: undefined symbol: PyCapsule_Type
```

I'm really at a lost as to what could be causing the error.  I have done `pip install rpy2` while having the virtual environment activated.  Is there some missing library I need?

Answer (score 0):

`PyCapsule` was backported from Python 3 and is only available on Python 2.7.

My guess is that your Django server is running Python 2.6 (may be the system's default Python) while having the `site-packages/` of python 2.7 in its package path.